# MySQL does not use index for BETWEEN and IN condition

Tags: mysql

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM
  events AS e
  WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM dissidentList
        WHERE actor_id IN (e.source_actor_id, e.target_actor_id)
              AND e.event_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM governmentList
        WHERE actor_id IN (e.source_actor_id, e.target_actor_id)
              AND e.event_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date);
```

I have indexes (MUL) on everything that appears in the query, including

```
events
-----------------------
event_date
source_actor_id
target_actor_id

dissidentList / governmentList
--------------------------
actor_id
start_date
end_date
```

However, nothing is being used. Why does this happen?

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table              | type | possible_keys       | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | e                  | ALL  | NULL                | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 19874715 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | anh_governmentList | ALL  | start_date,end_date | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   217890 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | anh_dissidentList  | ALL  | start_date,end_date | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    47452 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

**Q: Why does this happen?**

**A:** Likely the OR condition is disabling MySQL from considering using the index on the `actor_id` column. Note that the `foo IN (a,b)` is shorthand for `(foo = a OR foo = b)`

It is possible that MySQL might make use of a composite index, for example:

```
 ... ON dissidentList (start_date, end_date, actor_id)
 ... ON governmentList (start_date, end_date, actor_id)
```

The EXPLAIN output would show "Using index" if MySQL uses a covering index.

For table `events`, there are no sargable predicates. MySQL has to evaluate the `EXISTS` predicates for every row in the `events` table. (Also, the query is returning every column in the table, and there's no "covering" index that satisfies that SELECT list.)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q: What to do in this situation?**

**A:** If the addition of covering indexes on dissidentList and governmentList don't improve performance of the query, it may be possible to produce an equivalent result using JOIN operations. This might give better performance, but it will depend on the execution plan, and the cardinality.

Getting an equivalent result with a JOIN operation would require that the `events` table have a PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY on non-null column(s)). Because the JOIN operation can return multiple matches to `events`, we'd need to add a GROUP BY to eliminate the duplicates, and we'd use the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY columns for that.

Assuming that `id` is the name of the PRIMARY KEY column...

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM events e
  JOIN dissidentList f
    ON f.start_date <= e.event_date
   AND f.end_date   >= e.event_date
   AND f.actor_id   IN (e.source_actor_id, e.target_actor_id)
  JOIN governmentList g
    ON g.start_date <= e.event_date
   AND g.end_date   >= e.event_date
   AND g.actor_id   IN (e.source_actor_id, e.target_actor_id)
 GROUP BY e.id
```

Suitable covering indexes for both `dissidentList` and `governmentList` would improve performance:

```
... ON dissidentList (start_date, end_date, actor_id)
... ON governmentList (start_date, end_date, actor_id)
```

(We'd want EXPLAIN to show a "range" scan operation, and "Using index" in the extra column.)

MySQL may be able to make use of the PRIMARY KEY index on `events` to optimize the GROUP BY operation. If not, and if there a lot of matching rows in `dissidentList` and `governmentList`, this query could produce a very large intermediate result. If the EXPLAIN for this query shows 'Using temporary; Using filesort', this may be less efficient than the original. If the return from the query is a very small subset of events, it may be more efficient.

Comment: So what to do in this situation?

Comment: I have no idea what spencer is talking about, but I'm going to guess the solutions are `CREATE INDEX list_dates ON dissidentList (start_date, end_date, actor_id)` and defining which columns to return in SELECT clause instead of using *.

Comment: The answer looks promising... I didn't know that JOIN can be done using `>=` and `<=`!

Comment: Well, in fact the `type` is `all` still, and there's also `Using temporary; use filesort; use join buffer`.

Comment: @Heisenberg: I don't think there's any getting around evaluating every row in `events`. You're returning every column, so a full scan of `events` table may be the most efficient. Likely, it's the 20,000,000 executions the correlated subqueries that's the real performance killer. Getting the subqueries to be more efficient (with the addition of a suitable covering index), or eliminating the  individual executions by using a JOIN operation instead.

Comment: If I do a join of dissidentList and events, wouldn't that be a huge table and takes lots of time as well?

Comment: @Heisenberg: If there's lots of matching rows, then yes, it would be very large intermediate result. If MySQL spins all of those rows into a temporary table, that would take a lot of time. This would be more efficient if there were few matching rows, and if a very small subset of rows from events was returned.